# Issue with returning multiple files along with another variable from a python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am writing a script which will search the files of a pattern (mentioned in a list `req_text`) in a list `all_files`. if files of that pattern are found in a list `all_files` then it is returning `True` else it will return `false`

I am trying to return all the files using variable `f` but it is returning only 1 file instead of all the files mentioned in list `req_text`

code:

```
all_files = ['amc_20200304.txt', 'hello.py', 'pmc_20190807.txt', 'pmc_20200304.txt', 'pmc_20304.txt']
req_text = ['pmc_20304', 'abc']

# checking for files to be available
def file_check():    
    all_files = os.listdir(dir)
    for r in req_text:
        found = False
        for f in all_files:    
            if r in f:                         
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            return False
    return f, True
          
# polling to check if file exists or not
def poll_file_check():
    result = file_check()
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
result = ('abc.txt', True)
```

Expected output: returning all the files along with another variable `True`

```
result = [('abc.txt', pmc_20304.txt), True)]
```

any help would be appreciated and how can I fetch list of only files from the variable `result`, not `True`

Comment: firstly do you need the `true or false` to be `returned` in that function?? you can simply store `result` as a `list` of `files-found` , then check `len(result)` wherever you need `true or false`

Comment: You want [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/DroopyLumpyConditional#main.py)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain some sort of data structure (most probably a list) in which you will add the files for which `found` is True. So instead of just returning `f`, which can only take the name of one file, you should maintain a list to which you will add the files.

So something like this

```py
def file_check():
  filtered_files = []
  for r in req_text:
    for f in all_files:
      if r in f:
        filtered_files.append(f)
        break # So you don't add the file again

  return filtered_files, bool(filtered_files)
```

Note that using a tuple for maintaining file names won't work because [tuples are immutable](http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/10/python-tuples-immutable-but-potentially-changing.html). And you also don't need to maintain a `found` variable  because you know that you have found something if the `filtered_files` list has some content.

Comment: It will return list even only 1 file is present. I wanted to get the list returned only if all the files of pattern mentioned in list req_txt are found in a all_files list

Comment: I have answered my question. later figured it out

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using `list-comprehension`. Just change your `function definition` to this :

```
def file_check():    
    all_files = od.listdir(dir)
    return [f for f in all_files for r in req_text if r in f]
```

Output will be :

```
['abc.txt', 'pmc_20304.txt']
```

---

EDIT - If you only want to check `are all files of req-text variable in all-files variable?` , the function could make use of `all()` method in python :

```
# checking for files to be available
def file_check():    
    all_files = os.listdir(dir)
    return all([bool(r in all_files) for r in req_text])
```

Comment: It will return list even only 1 file is present. I wanted to get the list returned only if all the files of pattern mentioned in list req_txt are found in a directory

Comment: all method where?

Comment: This is returning true or false which is already happening in the question. I need list of all the files.  Anyways thank you for help

Comment: you mean , if only all the files of `req_txt` are found in `all_files` , it should return full list with true .and  if some files are not found , it should return empty list with false ?

Comment: I have answered my question. later figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
def file_check():    
    all_files = os.listdir(dir)
    print('Checking for required files...')
    for r in req_text:
        found = False
        for f in all_files:    
            if r in f:                         
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            return False
    return f, True
```